# Sum of same object name in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

Hi friends I'm beginner for javascript how i sum same n no's of object name corresponding value and push the result to new array.see this is sample object

`var obj_1 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};
 var obj_2 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'US'};
 var obj_nth ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};`

but i expect this output `[UK:{'delivered':20,'due':22},US:{'delivered':10,'due':11}]`,so please help me what i'll do next

Comment: Are those objects stored in an array ? Or is it just different variable ?

Comment: Put some code What you have tried.

Comment: yeah those obj store in an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can first create array of objects and then `reduce()` to return one object.

```js
var obj_1 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};
var obj_2 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'US'};
var obj_nth ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};

var result = [obj_1, obj_2, obj_nth].reduce(function(r, e) {
  if(!r[e.team_name]) {
    r[e.team_name] = {delivered:0,due:0}
  }
  r[e.team_name].delivered += e.delivered
  r[e.team_name].due += e.due
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Why `concat` and not simply `[o1, o2, o3]` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
const newArray = initialArray.map(({team_name, ...restProps}) => {
  return {
    [team_name]: {...restProps}
  };
});
```

See:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator)
- [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj_1 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};
var obj_2 ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'US'};
var obj_nth ={'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'};

function sum_all() { 
    var sum={}; 
    for(var i=0;i<arguments.length;i++) { 
        obj = arguments[i]; 
        if (!sum[obj.team_name]) { 
            sum[obj.team_name]={'delivered':0,'due':0}; 
        } 
        sum[obj.team_name].delivered += obj.delivered; 
        sum[obj.team_name].due += obj.due;    
    } 
    return sum; 
}

var sum = sum_all(obj_1,obj_2,obj_nth);

console.log(sum);
```

Your console output will be:

> ```
> sum
> Object
>   UK: Object
>       delivered: 20
>       due: 22
>
>   US: Object
>       delivered: 10
>       due: 11
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Store these objects in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), such as:

```
var myObjects = [
    {'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'},
    {'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'US'},
    {'delivered':10,'due':11,'team_name':'UK'}
];
```

Create a new object in which you will store your results:

```
var results = {};
```

Then iterate through the array with a for loop ([as it is generally faster](http://jsperf.com/for-vs-foreach/66)) and add the other properties according to `team_name`:

```
for (var i = 0; i <= myObjects.length; i++) {
    if (typeof results[myObjects[i].team_name] !== undefined) {
        results[myObjects[i]].delivered += myObjects[i].delivered;
        results[myObjects[i]].due += myObjects[i].due; 
    } else {
        // Set 0 to these properties if the entry didn't exist
        results[myObjects[i]].delivered = 0;
        results[myObjects[i]].due = 0;
    }
}
```